# Can't connect wifi adapter in vm ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, virtualization, vmware, adapter

I installed kali linux on vmware workstation but when i try to plug in a wifi adaptor i am getting this error

[image]
I don't know why i am facing this error because when i installed kali using vmware in my window machine the adaptor works fine but it's not connecting in ubuntu 20.04. I also create a extra USB port for the adaptor i don't know what to do please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by these commands:-

1. sudo apt install net-tools
2. sudo ifconfig wlan0 down

And the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by simply these commands:-

```
ifconfig command
nmcli command
systemctl command
nmtui command
Ip command
ifdown/ifup
```